# Undock a child window from main application

Tags: c++, winapi

let's say i have a big application with a few child windows inside of it. ( [example](http://quartushelp.altera.com/11.1/mergedProjects/global/image/gl_image_display_tabs_child_windows.gif) )

Now, i am trying to undock one of those "inside windows" to a new serperated window, which i can move all over the place!

What i have done so far:

```
HWND oldHWND = SetParent(hwnd, NULL);
SendMessage(oldHWND, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);
```

All this works very well, but i am not able to move the new window and i am not able to close it, because there is no window frame and no close button.

Do you have any suggestions for me?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Register a suitable window class for your undocked "floating" window with a frame/close button etc, and then make the undocked window a child of that.